# Wix Detox E2E tests - Improving Speed

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator, detox

My E2E tests currently takes about 8 mins for 24 tests - they are pretty simple scenarios and shouldn't take time.

A lot of time is spent on tapping elements ( i am guessing it's waiting for searching the element in the UI Hierarchy )

Any tips on how to improve performance - the demos seem pretty fast, so its a possibility there is something I am doing which is incorrect.

How long does your E2E takes and when you search for elements do you do hierarchy search or id-search?

Detox version: 6.0.2
RN version:0.50.4
XCODE:9.2
simulator: 10.3

Comment: does your app has network or animation processes taking place while the tests are running?

Comment: No, but it does have interactions over the network. although it takes forever to click on buttons. So I truly suspect it's wasting time searching elements

Comment: What happens when you run Detox demo app "demo-react-native" under your setup conditions: Detox version: 6.0.2 RN version:0.50.4 XCODE:9.2 simulator: 10.3? Does it run fast or slow?

Comment: The same for me... tests are very very slow. I tried detox example app and their tests run in about 1s each. But that app is so simple that I have no idea how this could tell me anything useful